# Не обновляется содержимое QListWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, sqlite, qlistwidget

Имеется программа на *PyQt5*, на главном экране которого расположены два списка (`QListWidget`), в которые подгружаются данные из базы данных *SQLite*.

Под списками расположены кнопки "Добавить", "Удалить" и "Переместить". При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" открывается маленькое окно, где нужно заполнить строку (`QLineEdit`), и нажать на кнопку "Добавить" уже в этом окне (маленьком).

В **main.py** есть функция `up_list()`, которая очищает `QListWidget` и добавляет в список данные из БД. Эта функция прекрасно работает, если вызвать его из того же класса, в котором она объявлялась (`App`), но если вызвать его из другого класса (`Dialod_UI`, класс со вторым окном), она не срабатывает. 
Точнее, сама функция запускается (в этом можно убедится потому, как выводится `print()` из этой функции), но сам список не обновляется.

Пробовал реализовать это с помощью `PyQtSignal`, ничего не меняется.
Кстати, забиндил функцию `up_list()` на первую кнопку "Удалить", всё срабатывает как нужно, список после нажатия на эту кнопку обновляется.

Мне нужно, чтобы список обновлялся точно так же, только после нажатия на кнопку "Добавить" из дополнительного, маленького окна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код прилагается:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
import time

import main_ui
import dialog_ui
from db import DataBase


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.init_UI() 


    def init_UI(self):
        self.main_ui = main_ui.Ui_Form()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self)


        self.dialog_ui = Dialod_UI()
        self.db = DataBase()

        self.l_items = self.main_ui.listWidget
        self.l_items_2 = self.main_ui.listWidget_2
        self.up_list()

        self.main_ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.up_list)
        self.main_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dialog_ui.show)


        self.l_items.itemClicked.connect(self.item_delete)
        self.l_items_2.itemClicked.connect(self.item_delete_2)

        self.main_ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.l_items_2.addItem('test'))


    def up_list(self):
        print('есть сигнал')
        self.l_items.clear()
        self.l_items_2.clear()

        for value_mto in self.db.sql.execute('SELECT mark FROM cartridge_mto'):
            self.l_items.addItems(value_mto)

        for value in self.db.sql.execute('SELECT mark FROM cartridge'):
            self.l_items_2.addItems(value)

    def item_delete(self, item):
        print(f'Первый список: {item.text()}')

    def item_delete_2(self, item):
        print(f'Второй список: {item.text()}')


class Dialod_UI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialod_UI, self).__init__()
        self.setup_dialod()

    def setup_dialod(self):
        self.dialog_ui = dialog_ui.Ui_Form()
        self.dialog_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.dialog_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_in_db), self.dialog_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def add_in_db(self):
        self.db = DataBase()
        self.i = self.dialog_ui.lineEdit.text()
        if self.i != '':
            self.db.sql.execute(f'INSERT INTO cartridge_mto VALUES (?)', (self.i,))
            self.db.db.commit()

        self.app = App()
        self.app.up_list()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**db.py**

```
import sqlite3


class DataBase():
    db = sqlite3.connect('D:\\Python\\Картриджи\\server.db')
    sql = db.cursor()

    sql.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cartridge_mto (mark TEXT)')
    sql.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cartridge (mark TEXT)')


    db.commit()
```

**main_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(800, 598)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 311, 431))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 30, 311, 431))
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 470, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 470, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 470, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 470, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 470, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 470, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "ДОБАВИТЬ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "УДАЛИТЬ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "ПЕРЕСЕСТИТЬ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "ПЕРЕСЕСТИТЬ"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "УДАЛИТЬ"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "ДОБАВИТЬ"))
```

**dialog_ui.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'dialog_ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(393, 200)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 291, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("padding: 5px;\n"
"border: 2px solid black;\n"
"border-radius: 5px;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid black;\n"
"border-radius: 5px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "ДОБАВИТЬ"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Напишите метку на картридже"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "и название принтера"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
# ??? import time

from main_ui import  Ui_Form as Ui_Form_main
from dialog_ui import  Ui_Form as Ui_Form_dialog

from db import DataBase


class Dialod_UI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
# !!!                  vvvvvv
    def __init__(self, parent):                                # +++ parent
        super(Dialod_UI, self).__init__()
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.setup_dialod()

    def setup_dialod(self):
        self.dialog_ui = Ui_Form_dialog()               # dialog_ui.Ui_Form()
        self.dialog_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.dialog_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(
            self.add_in_db), self.dialog_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def add_in_db(self):
        self.db = DataBase()
        self.i = self.dialog_ui.lineEdit.text()
        if self.i != '':
            self.db.sql.execute(f'INSERT INTO cartridge_mto VALUES (?)', (self.i,))
            self.db.db.commit()

#        self.app = App()
#        self.app.up_list()
# !!!        vvvvvv
        self.parent.up_list()                                 # +++ 


# !!!               vvvvvvv
class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):         # - (QtWidgets.QMainWindow): нет
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.init_UI() 

    def init_UI(self):
        self.main_ui = Ui_Form_main()                 # main_ui.Ui_Form()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self)

        self.dialog_ui = Dialod_UI(self)                      # +++ self
        self.db = DataBase()

        self.l_items = self.main_ui.listWidget
        self.l_items_2 = self.main_ui.listWidget_2
        self.up_list()

        self.main_ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.up_list)
        self.main_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dialog_ui.show)

        self.l_items.itemClicked.connect(self.item_delete)
        self.l_items_2.itemClicked.connect(self.item_delete_2)

        self.main_ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.l_items_2.addItem('test'))

    def up_list(self):
        print('есть сигнал')
        self.l_items.clear()
        self.l_items_2.clear()

        for value_mto in self.db.sql.execute('SELECT mark FROM cartridge_mto'):
            self.l_items.addItems(value_mto)
        for value in self.db.sql.execute('SELECT mark FROM cartridge'):
            self.l_items_2.addItems(value)

    def item_delete(self, item):
        print(f'Первый список: {item.text()}')

    def item_delete_2(self, item):
        print(f'Второй список: {item.text()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не сомневался в твоей помощи. Проблема решена, большое спасибо!